# How to access a specific object in a class HTML while web scraping with python

Tags: python, list, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Now, I understand that this may be a simple question, but I don't know anything about HTML and I'm new to web scraping with python. I was wondering if anyone could tell me how to access this specific object in this class on this website (https://sky.lea.moe/stats/Igris/Apple). The specific object I want to access is in HTML below.
'''
Average Skill Level: 
32.5 == $0
'''
My current code looks like this and prints out an empty list, and even if it did print, I only want it to print out everything from this specific line of code shown above.

```
import bs4

res = requests.get('https://sky.lea.moe/stats/Igris/Apple')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
type(soup)

skillAverageList = []

for i in soup.select('.stat-value'):
     skillAverageList.append(i.text)
```

Any help would be appreciated, hopefully this will further help me understand HTML and python as a whole. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get('https://sky.lea.moe/stats/Igris/Apple')

soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')

print(soup.find("div", {"id":"additional_stats_container"}).find_all("div",class_="additional-stat")[-2].get_text(strip=True))
```

Output:

```
Average Skill Level:32.5
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
elements = soup.find_all("span", class_="stat-name")
skill = [i for i in elements if "Average Skill" in i.text] #getting element that has "Average Skill" in its text
idx = elements.index(skill) #getting its index to get the value of same index from values
values = soup.find_all("span", class_="stat-value")
value = values[idx] #as told earlier index of name would be same for value
print(skill[0].text + value.text)
```

Comment: Yours worked just as intended as well!! Thanks a lot!